# AWS Access KEY ,Secret key access via python script

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am new to PYTHON and AWS . In my project ,if i want to do call s3 operation , before that i need to call start.py which have below code.

```
from credentials import credentials

res = credentials.credentials(DurationSeconds=10000)

print(res)
```

after executing above code , it is printing aws_secret_key,access_key in my console.
How can i implement the same in my local machine to set those variable? i have installed python 3 in my local machine

1. what are the module required?
2. Any Prestep required ..

Please share your ideas?

Note : installed s3fs module , and ran the code. it is causing credentials.credentials - module not available.

Comment: I recommend that you use Python boto3 to access AWS.

Comment: Have any link/ doc  to help step by step process.

Comment: BTW, i need to follow the same step to replicate into another env. also..

Comment: What exactly are you asking for, Do you want to restart your instance and/or do what with it? by py script?

Comment: if i am executing above script , it is printing (res - variable) - aws_key,secret_key and session value. Question is are they doing any extra configuration at host level? credentials.credentials() - what will do ?

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html . you can go through the quickstart to get an idea.